# How to monitor an external hard drive for data quality / health

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, monitoring

Not knowing anything about hard drives, I am wondering how a cloud service provider monitors their hard drives for problems (data corruption, loss of data, hard drive failure, etc.). Searching google doesn't reveal much other than "download your hard drive manufacturers repair kit and press repair". I would like to know what is happening in that repair process, and better yet, how a cloud provider regularly monitors their hard drives for quality. I read somewhere that BackBlaze does a [*daily* SMART stats analysis](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/what-smart-stats-indicate-hard-drive-failures/) sort of thing, to see how their hard drives are doing, but I'm not sure really what that means.

> We use [Smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) to capture the SMART data.

The repo is [here](https://github.com/smartmontools/smartmontools/tree/master/smartmontools), but I would like to know what this Smartmontools is doing. Not necessarily in detail, but a quick outline. Can't really tell from the repo what it does.

What I imagine would happen (to monitor a hard drive) is this. Create a database with MD5 hashes of every file. Periodically scan the entire hard drive and do a checksum with every file against the saved MD5 hash. But this seems like it would be very slow, especially on terabytes hard drives. I am not really sure what kinds of failures you can have, and what kinds of notifications you can get. Maybe you can use [file system events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents), but I'm not sure how that would work on an external drive rather than on the main machine. But even if it did work on the external hard drive, I'm not sure it would be notified when data got corrupted because of the device getting old. So it seems the only way to check that the data is correct is to actually compare the current data with the old data. But other than a checksum I'm not really sure what efficient way could be done to do this.

The main thing you would want in the monitoring process is to know when a drive is starting to not work as well, so you can get ready to change it. Repairing a drive is a whole other thing which I don't know how it works, but I won't ask that here. I would just like to know how you typically monitor an external hard drive, and and how you know when it is starting to not work correctly (i.e. how you know if data has been corrupted/lost in an efficient way, and things like that).

[This](https://www.quora.com/How-do-data-recovery-tools-work-As-a-programmer-I-want-to-learn-how-we-read-a-raw-drive-and-then-recover-it-programmatically-and-which-programming-language-is-used) seems to offer some information.

Instead of just knowing "just apply x technology", I would like to know how to actually implement it as like an app or or something, at least the basics to get started.

Comment: One SMART thing to monitor is the ECC or number of Error Correction done by the hard drive.  Initially it will be 0, but as the hard drive ages it will increase and even go into the 100's millions(at this point the drive is so slow its painful(believe me I have experienced it first hand)).  Each ECC slows down the read/write cycle so the speed will degrade over time.

Answer (score 0):

"I am wondering how a cloud service provider monitors their hard drives for problems"

They don't really. Drives usually fail suddenly. The answer is to build systems that survive failure. The big cloud services use massive clusters of servers, in multiple buildings, have servers that use mirrored RAID arrays (which store data redundantly), and have servers that mirror other servers.

So redundant locations, redundant servers, redundant drives in servers.

Google has released studies about their disk failure rates etc. and basically: SMART is mainly useless and drive failures take a large jump at about 3 years.

Get a second drive in the mix, mirror them (robocopy (part of windows) is a great choice for consumers), and replace them every three years. If you can get copy of your data off-site, do it.

Fixing drives is only good to get stuff off them you don't have backups for. You cannot trust them any longer and they should be ditched. If you have a mirrored backup, you just replace the failed drive mirror the existing data onto it, and move on.

I use a low power device as a server on my LAN with two matching external drives (I look for something big around $100). I push backups to a server drive, and the server schedules a routine mirroring operation to duplicate the backup to the other drive. I also image my important machine(s) once in a while so I can recover the OS install if needed.

I replace the external disks every few years, and usually wind up taking the drive out of the enclosure and using it for bulk storage of non-critical data e.g. games in one of my main machines until the next round.